# django redirect to other protocol than http android

Tags: android, django, http, redirect

Is there any way to redirect a User's browser to something other than http?
When a user hits a certain page, I would like to redirect the user's browser to my_android_application:///some_domain
instead of http://some_domain

my android app knows to intercept my_android_application:///

Everything I seem to find on redirects in django only pertain to http. Is there anyway to redirect to my protocol instead?

(I know that it's considered better practice to intercept something like http://some_domain/interceptAndroidApp, but I don't want a Complete Action pop-up on the phone showing up at all)

Answer (score 1):

A META refresh might work. Send a regular HTTP 200 response (content type text/html) with the following content:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=my_android_application:///some_domain">
```

---

<strike>On second thought, I think this would work much better:</strike>

```
response = HttpResponse(content="", status=302)
response["Location"] = "my_android_application:///some_domain"
```

Comment: the response["Location"] solution just gets appended to current domain. it becomes  http://localhost/my_android_application:///some_domain

Comment: This is the same behavior for using HttpResponseRedirect - if its not http, it assumes that the url is just a path for the current domain

Comment: I see. Perhaps the META approach is the better one, then.